# Magento 2.2.1 composer upgrade issue amazon pay

Tags: upgrade, composer, magento-2.2.1, amazon-payment

I tried to upgrade **Magento 2.2.0** to version **2.2.1** via **composer** however i received framework error about amazon pay conflict (my amazon pay version is 1.1.4). I'm aware i need to update amazon pay to version 1.2.0 first so i can update Magento to 2.2.1.

So i run commands:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 --no-update

composer require amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin:^1.2.0 --no-update

composer update
```

And i got an error:

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.1].
- amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module 1.2.0 requires magento/framework ^100.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.2.0-rc20, 100.1.9, 100.1.10].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.0-rc1].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.0-rc2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.0-rc3].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.0].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.1].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.3].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.4].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.5].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.6].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.7].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.8].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.2.0-rc20].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.9].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.10, 101.0.1].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 requires magento/framework 101.0.1 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.1].
- Installation request for amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module 1.2.0 -> satisfiable by amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module[1.2.0].
```

I think my mistake was to run both updates at the same time, and now when I try to update Amazon Pay with below command to version 1.2.0

Command:

```
composer require amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin:^1.2.0
```

I get Error:

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/product-community-edition (locked at 2.2.0, required as 2.2.1) is satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.1].
    - amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module 1.2.0 requires magento/framework ^100.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.2.0-rc20, 100.1.9, 100.1.10].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.0-rc1].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.0-rc2].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.0-rc3].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.2].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.4].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.6].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.7].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.8].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.2.0-rc20].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.9].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.10, 101.0.1].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 requires magento/framework 101.0.1 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.1].
    - Installation request for amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module 1.2.0 -> satisfiable by amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module[1.2.0].
```

It looks like it still tries to run both updates at the same time... How can i 'unlock' it and only update Amazon pay to version 1.2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution myself, i have changed Magento version back to current version 2.2.0 in composer.json file in magento root folder

```
"require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.0"
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin": "1.2.0",
```

It stopped Magento from requesting update to version 2.2.1 and i could only update amazon pay after that running simply

```
composer update
```